# XCode-iOS : What does this linker warning mean "file was built for unsupported file format "

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to get some a medium-to-large sized code base that is, frankly, well written with a high degree of portability.

I decided to package it as a loadable bundle (plugin) and piggy-backed off of one of the template app projects and followed some tutorials about adding a target for loadable bundles within an app.

Also, this loadable bundle depends on a custom framework which I built for iOS and added it as a dependent for the loadable bundle.  ie. The plugin links to a framework wrapper for a static lib.

The custom framework built successfully.  Granted I have not yet verified that it works.  The idea is to test the integrated functionality.

My build settings are largely defaults with the exception of some preprocessor defines.

Because I don't really understand the code base yet, I am literally adding one file-at-a-time to the plugin target and building cleanly every 3-4 files added.

The build completes successfully but with many, many warnings as follows, with paths to intermediate build results...etc.:

"file was built for unsupported file format with a series of hex characters () which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s)".  When I converted the hex chars to ascii it just showed "#1 /Users/my-username/? ".

When I do a 'file' on any .o in the intermediate build results, I get "ASCII c program text, with very long lines"

What am I doing wrong?  What does that mean?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I don't have your project in front of me to look at the settings, but my guess is that you need to modify the supported architectures of your custom framework project.  They should support "`armv7s`" at a minimum, and probably also "`i386`" (simulator) as well.

Comment: Michael: thanks for taking the time to respond.  I added i386 as you suggested, but the message continued.  In fact, I made sure the build settings followed iOS Defaults as suggested when you click "Levels", but I still get the same odd message.

Comment: please read the new update: the ascii equivalent of the hex chars is "#1 /Users/<user name>/? "

Comment: The files you are adding are they from an existing Xcode project or are you porting this from another IDE? Could the underlying files not be UTF8/UTF16 encoded?

Comment: @Michael Here is an update 1-I deleted the intermediates by pressing command-option-shift-k within Xcode.I quit it, then manually deleted projects' folders in the DerivedData folder.2- I then went through the project and target settings within the main project and its target , as well as the custom framework's project and its target and made sure that the language settings were the defaults. (I undid some GNU-compatibility related options that I previously set). I did a build of both, and my 300 warnings went down to 105 of the same linker warning. I think I'll have to peruse those 105 files.

Comment: @Flexicoder: the sources are not from another IDE, but your question is very interesting.  I will check and let you know.

Comment: this is starting not to look good: when I do a 'file' on any .o in the intermediate build results, I get "ASCII c program text, with very long lines"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is this:

If you get this message, then your project settings are messed up.

1. If you are linking your app against custom frameworks, make sure they are built as fat binaries
2. You will need to know very clearly the meanings of active architecture and how it is used and whether or not you want to only build the active architecture for your app, or all of the possible architectures.
3. If you are, like me, inheriting a slew of portable code that depended heavily on gcc and its extensions, expect to make changes around **builtin* attributes and to make heavy use of __clang** to make available macros that used to be defined through the **GNUC** et al.
4. Also, you will need to use the -E for clang to debug/understand the preprocessing and the file inclusion.  That said, **don't forget to take it out** because effectively what will happen is that your .o will just contain text and the build may succeed, but the linker will give you the odd message subject of this question.
5. Finally, do understand that Xcode, like any piece of complex software, is **buggy**.  Sometimes, it will keep settings that you get rid off.  In my case, I included custom frameworks which I built after placing them in a local dir.  Then I deleted them from the project and opted to trash when prompted.  The build kept failing because the linker for some reason was looking for the local directory. You would have to edit the *.pbxproj and manually remove them.